# Is it possible to obtain the end date of execution of a file in C++?

Tags: c++, datetime, trace, execution-time

how can we get the end date of execution of the file.
Actually,I have created a file who write in a file.

I would like to write in this file, the end date of execution, that's is possible ?

My file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void writeOn(fstream& file) {

    if(file)
    {
        string name = "Peter";
        string nickname = "Shanks";

        file << "Hi, " << name << endl;
        file << __DATE__ << ":" << __TIME__ << endl;
    }
    else
        cerr << "Unable to open file" << endl;

int main() {
    fstream file("trace.log", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    writeOn(file);
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Perhaps you could edit it to contain a single, simple question?

Comment: @Poldie : I wannt to write the end date of the execution of the file ... what's unclear for you, tell me please and I will try to explain.

Comment: "how can we get the end date of execution of the file." looks like a question, but no question mark.  Is this the same as the next question? If so, remove the first one as it's unclear.  Writing a date to a file sounds different to "getting" the "end date of execution" of a file, which sounds like a property of the file itself, rather than the contents.  There's some bad grammar/spelling in there too, which can be ignored/clarified once the basic question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following at start of execution and at end of execution

```
#include <ctime>

//.....

std::time_t result = std::time(NULL);
file << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result)) << std::endl ;
```

Ref : [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time)

Comment: that would be the compilation date and time.

Comment: @POW : It's normal that I have the day only for the end date ?, that's what I have : Aug  6 2014:14:09:11/nWed Aug  6 14:09:15 2014, and could you comment your response please ( you are more strong than me )